# How to debug request from Behat scenario?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, vagrant, xdebug, behat

I know how to use xdebug with behat for basic usage. I'm working with Drupal & Behat. It seems that for every scenario Drupal is boostrapped only once. Breakpoints there were hit once. Besides this I can debug Context class code, but in case of one of my custom steps:

```
$this->getSession()->visit('node/' . $this->node_id);
```

I cannot debug code executed upon page visit by behat.
What can I do to allow such debug possibility?

I'm working in Vagrant context also.